# udev creates device file for USB key, but not for partitions

Tags: 11.10, udev

Most USB keys work on my system: plug one in and `udev` will create a device file for the key as a whole (e.g. `/dev/uba`), as well as a device file for the partition (e.g. `/dev/uba1`).

I have a specific USB key (a Sandisk Cruzer Micro 2Gb) which `udev` misbehaves with. The device file for the key is created, but not for the partition.

If I compare the `dmesg` output between a working key and my problem key, it is identical except for one line which is missing when using the problem key: `uba: uba1`. It would appear from this that `mknod` is never creating a node for the disk partition.

The weird thing is that I can do...

```
sudo sfdisk -R /dev/uba
```

...to force drive partitions to be re-examined and suddenly the partition will be recognised, `mknod` will create a device file it and I can access the key all fine and dandy like. Some kind of timing issue?

### EDIT:

**Automount USB Rules:**

```
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="ub[a-z]*[1-9]*", PROGRAM="/sbin/blkid -o values -s TYPE %N", RESULT=="vfat", RUN+="/home/ubuntu/.mount_usb %k %n"
ACTION=="remove", KERNEL=="ub[a-z]*", RUN+="/home/ubuntu/.unmount_usb"
```

**Also:**
The problem key defaults to FAT16 when being reformatted. Forcing it to FAT32 results in `udevadm monitor --property` spitting out exactly the same properties for the device and partition as for a working key, but the problem still remains. This leads me to think that it's less likely to be a problem with the device detection rules and perhaps a problem with the device itself? Is this a logical conclusion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just from the `/dev/uba` naming structure, it sounds like you created your own UDEV rule and now it's not working out for you. We'll need to see that code to assist you.

I'm sure you've consulted this already but just in case please consult this reference for creating UDEV rules. http://wiki.debian.org/udev

**Feedback based on update**

```
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="ub[a-z]*[1-9]*", PROGRAM="/sbin/blkid -o values -s TYPE %N", RESULT=="vfat", RUN+="/home/ubuntu/.mount_usb %k %n"
ACTION=="remove", KERNEL=="ub[a-z]*", RUN+="/home/ubuntu/.unmount_usb"
```

It looks like your predecessor didn't know about `usbmount`. This rule will only
work on vfat formatted drives, now you could expand that list, or... you could install
`usbmount` and tweak it to create the device names you want. Then you have something
that's maintained for you with only minor configuration changes vs a complete home brew
solution.

BTW, there's a syntax error in there, it's `value` not `values`, running this from the CLI shows.

```
sudo blkid -o value -s TYPE /dev/sdb1
vfat
```

So the `%N` is the input, e.g. the block device and RESULT is stdout. This is detailed in the udev man page. You might be able to do something like this `RESULT=="[vfat|fat16]"`, or you could forward the output to a script and do a richer comparison there. A quick look at the usbmount package shows that rich comparisons are done in the callout script for both add and remove. I strongly recommend you migrate to `usbmount`.

Comment: I've inherited this issue and it's the first time I've gotten down and dirty with Ubuntu, so please assume that I'm ignorant of anything outside the research shown above! That said, I did think it was odd that my devices are being named ub* rather than sb*. I have four sets of rules in `/etc/udev/rules.d`: `60-automount-usb`, `70-persistent-cd`, `70-persistent-net`, `80-usb-permissions`. All seem irrelevant, except the `automount` set (which I've added above) - but even that seems like a response to the partition device file being added rather than the specification for how to create the file.

Comment: Alright then, if it were me, I would seek and destroy that entire rule as it offers no value. Just grep until you find it and remove the ruleset. The *right way* to do this is scan for something unique, like make, model, and serial #, and then create a **symlink**  to the normal sdx devices. This way you keep all the original devices in place, including the partition probing, and you just mixin your additional label. The reason you're not seeing a partition is whoever made that ubX rule failed to run `partprobe` or equivalent on the raw device. Hope this helps.

Comment: Cheers for the continued help! I don't understand though, I need the rule above to my automount script so I can't just get rid of it. Don't I need to find the rule that actually creates the ubX device in the first place? And wherever that rule is defined, if it's missing a `partprobe` why do some keys work and some don't? Surely it would either work or it wouldn't? Sorry if I'm being wilfully dense :P

Comment: This is where it get's complicated, I need to see the actual script. My current assumption is the rule is creating a new ubX block device **instead** of creating an sdx block device. I would like to leave block device creation alone and instead **symlink to the proven sdx block devices**. It'll also be easier to maintain as you're just an ls -l away to finding out what that device really is. As for it's inconsistency, udev is premised on pattern and rule matching, without seeing the original rule, I can only speculate as to why it's not running consistently. You're not dense, UDEV is awkward.